# Postfix error: not yet authorized to deliver mail

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I am running a private postfix server for my domain `mydomain.com`, on server `111.111.111.111` (IP and domain sanitized for privacy reasons)

I have sent an email to `info@example.com` which is on server `222.222.222.222`. The message was deferred, and in my postfix logs, I could see following error:

```
postfix/smtp  9D055EA: host mail1.example.com[222.222.222.222] said: 
451-111.111.111.111 is not yet authorized to deliver mail from 451 
<martin@mydomain.com> to <info@example.com>. Please try later. (in 
reply to RCPT TO command)
```

My domain has reverse DNS record set up, and I am using SPF record. Both are configured correctly, I can send emails all right, this is the first case when I have seen these errors.

This leads me to believe, that this error is caused by misconfiguration on the destination server. But since I am not sure what these errors mean, I would like if somebody could explain it.

Comment: Does the destination server have greylisting enabled?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill - I don't know. The destination server is not under my control.

Comment: Did the retry succeed after sometime?

Comment: @clement - I did not wait to see if it would have succeeded. I have removed  the mail from  queue and sent it from gmail instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message "... is not yet authorized to deliver mail from ..." is similar to a greylist implementation described in [Adding Greylisting Support](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Spam-Filtering-for-MX/exim-greylisting.html).
If the destination server implement similar script, you can send your mail by flushing your queue to retry sending soon.

```
$ postqueue -f
```

The greylist implementation works as follows;

1. If a mail come from an unauthorized host, the server replies 451 and save a entry including sender/recipient/IP/...
2. When the host retry to send the mail, the server checks whether all sender/recipient/IP are matched. If matched, the server accept the mail.

I think this idea is come from most spammer implementation.
It sends many mails to random recipient with random sender addresses. So it never send to the same recipient.